# fail to load arff file in python

Tags: python, arff

I am quite sure that my arff files are correct, for that I have downloaded different files on the web and successfully opened them in Weka.

But I want to use my data in python, then I typed:

```
import arff
data = arff.load('file_path','rb')
```

It always returns an error message: *Invalid layout of the ARFF file*, at line 1.

Why this happened and how should I do to make it right?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. We would either need to see the start of your ARFF file, or get a working crystal ball. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you change your code like in below, it'll work.

```
import arff
data = arff.load(open('file_path'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using scipy we can load arff data in python

```
from scipy.io import arff

import pandas as pd

data = arff.loadarff('dataset.arff')

df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])

df.head()
```